# Copy file from iPhone app to iTunes

Tags: iphone, file, itunes, synchronization, ringtone

I am trying to figure out how to copy a ringtone file (.m4r) embedded in the app to iTunes when connected. After the file is copied into iTunes, they can simply sync the file like every other file. I know this is possible, since there are other ringtone apps that do this exact same thing. If someone could point me in the right direction or maybe provide some sample code, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to bump this thread. I figure using iTunes file sharing is the way, but I can't get my app to show up in the iTunes file sharing section in iTunes. Is there something else you have to do other than setting "UIFileSharingEnabled" to true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share files from your app's Documents directory with iTunes. Simply add the following XML to your info.plist:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Now, files in your app's Documents directory will appear in the File Sharing section of iTunes. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yeah I have been looking into that since I posted. My info.plist file looks quite a bit different from what I have seen others. For example, most people have a number of CF.... (CFBundleName, etc.) where mine just says "Bundle Name". Instead of "UIFileSharingEnabled", mine says "Application supports iTunes file sharing". I assume that isn't a problem, however, I set that to true but my app still isn't showing up in the list of file sharing apps in iTunes. Is there something else I need to do to get it to show up. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I looked at the actual xml code and it does show the names as described "UIFileSharingEnable", but I still don't know why I can't get my app to appear in the apps file sharing list in iTunes. It has the other apps listed that use file sharing, just not mine.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I'm not sure what actually fixed that problem (since I made a number of modifications), but it may have just needed to be uninstalled from the device and then reinstalled.

Comment: If you use the GUI to do this, Apple names the key "Application supports iTunes file sharing"