# export dynamically generated audio file from iphone app to iphone itunes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, synchronization, itunes

I am looking into developing an Iphone app that generates noises based on user input and exports it to a file.

How can I export this file in such a way that it goes into the iTunes library on the iphone? My goal is to make iTunes sync all of the generated files (in the normal way used for music in the user's library) instead of having the user manually access the app's shared files and copy them over to his computer from there, as described here:
[Copy file from iPhone app to iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463456/copy-file-from-iphone-app-to-itunes)

Thanks

Comment: iTunes won't sync your files automatically.

Comment: If my answer is correct, please mark it as so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The user will probably have to manually copy it over themselves. For example, this is why ringtone apps require you to make the ringtone, then copy it over into iTunes, and then copy it back to your device as a ringtone before you can use it.